# List<?> list = new ArrayList<String>(); List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Tags: java, generics

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

These two object we can not add anything in the list, if we will try to add anything it will show a compile time error.

Please tell me where we are using it or what will its use?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you cannot add anything to `List<?>` is exactly the type safety offered by the wildcard (well, compare to `List<Object>` in this case). And that type safety will only be realized when you want to use the List.

`List<?>` conveys the idea that "you don't care what the list is made of". In other words, it means "your code will run safely no matter what is in the list, and no matter what you do to the list". Your code will not run type-safely if it allows you to add element to the list. You can search the SO to see why.

When do you want to use `List<?>`:

```
 public int countNonNull (List<?> list){
    int count = 0;
    for (Object item : list) {
         if (item != null) count ++;
    }
    return count;
 }
```

for a function defined as above, you can invoke it with any kind of list:

```
countNonNull(new ArrayList<String>());
countNonNull(new ArrayList<Integer>());
countNonNull(new ArrayList<Date>());
```

You cannot do the same without the wildcard. By scarifying the capability to insert to the list, the compiler allows you to write more general and expressive code .

There is no difference between `List<?>` and `List <? extends Object>`. Just like there is no difference between `class A {}`and `class A extends Object {}`